# Newton's Law of Gravity with ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question seems very vague, confusing this question seems to need first order ODE? having trouble doing this question while solving a past exam

A) Earth can be considered as a perfect sphere of mass M and radius R = 6378km.
For a particle of mass m located beneath the surface of the earth, at a distance r
from the centre, the gravitational force attracting the mass towards the centre is
$\mathbf F_r = −\frac
{GM_rm}{r^
2}$
, where Mr
is the mass of the Earth contained within a sphere of
radius r.

(a) Show that $\mathbf F_r = −\frac
{GMm_r}
{R^3}$
.

Comment: what does this have to do with ordinary differential equations?

Comment: I'm also not sure what diferrential equations come into play here...at best this is an integral problem which proves [Poisson's Equation for Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Newtonian_gravity).

Comment: regarding the last edit, should it be $m_r$ or $m r$?

Comment: That should certainly be $mr$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need an ODE?
$M_r = (4/3) \pi r^3 \rho_r$

$M = (4/3) \pi R^3 \rho_R$

Assuming uniform density... (which is questionable) but seems to be what the answer requires.

$M_r/M = r^3/R^3$

$M_r = M\, r^3/R^3$

Substituting this into $GM_rm/r^2 = GMm\, r/R^3$

Comment: It was the first question on last years ordinary differential equation exam so I assumed I need to solve it using ODE. for M_r and M do we just assume they are uniform density p? since the question does not outline anything about density

Answer (score 1):

We will use Gauss's Law for Gravity. We have

$$\int \boldsymbol{g} \cdot d\boldsymbol{A} = -4 \pi G M_{r}$$

Taking advantage of symmetry, we have

$$ 4 \pi r^2 \boldsymbol{g} = -4 \pi G (\frac{\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 }{\frac{4}{3} \pi R^3}M) \>\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}$$

$$\boldsymbol{g} = \frac{-GMr}{R^3} \> \boldsymbol{\hat{r}} $$

Using Newton's Law, we have

$$ \boldsymbol{F} = \frac{-GMmr}{R^3} \> \boldsymbol{\hat{r}}$$